# Lazarus FindWindow do not work when Window Name Contain non-English string

Tags: lazarus

```
a:=FindWindow(nil, PChar('你好，世界'));
if a <> 0 then ShowMessage('hello');
```

this above code cannot found window by name `'你好，世界'` in lazarus, but work in delphi 7 and above version of delphi

Comment: You need to use FindWindowW and make sure the text is encoded as UTF16

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I tried change to `a:=FindWindowW(nil, PWideChar(UnicodeString('你好，世界')));` also not works

Comment: Then clearly you are not passing correctly encoded text, or there is no window with that name.

Comment: Try inserting `{$codepage utf8}` on top of your unit without any casts (i.e. `FindWindowW(nil, '你好，世界');`). Read string literals in [this topic](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Unicode_Support_in_Lazarus).